# Do snakemake-wrappers get fetched once and stored locally? Or fetched everytime from remote URL?

Tags: snakemake

When [snakemake wrappers](https://snakemake-wrappers.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) are used with snakemake scripts, do they get fetched everytime from remote URL or are they stored locally? I don't see them stored anywhere in `.snakemake` directory, which makes me think it gets fetched everytime even if same version of wrapper script is used everytime.

Comment: You could try switching off the internet and see if they still work? If it does work they are stored, if it doesn't you still don't know :)

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande Thanks to you, I got out of the lazy chair and tested it :)

Comment: PS- Since yesterday, my pipeline which heavily uses conda and snakemake wrappers kept freezing at the stage of figuring out the conda envs necessary. Debugging shows remote wrapper is the issue and local copy via `--wrapper-prefix` solves the problem. Noting it here in case others had similar trouble. Snakemake version used - 5.9.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Snakemake does fetch wrapper script from remote URL everytime, and currently there doesn't appear to be a solution to change this behavior. One alternative is to have a local clone of the wrapper repository and point snakemake to it using [`--wrapper-prefix`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#all-options).

Here is the error message when internet is not available:

```sh
RuleException:
WorkflowError in line 16 of /Users/blah/Downloads/Snakefile:
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>
  File "/Users/blah/Downloads/Snakefile", line 16, in __rule_tabix
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
```